# JUnit exception in main?

Tags: java, macos, junit

I am trying to run a simple junit test using OS X and terminal. I have placed the Junit jar file inside my java folder. I was able to compile all of the files using:

```
javac -cp .:"/Library/java/junit.jar" *.java
```

It compiles just fine, with no errors. However when I try to run the command:

```
java TestRunner
```

It gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
    at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

I cannot seem to find what I am doing incorrectly. Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have to admin I'm a bit rough on classpaths, but don't you have to add the dependencies to the classpath when you actually run the code too? I also recommend using a build tool like gradle, ant or maven to handle all of this stuff for you, this is just a big waste of time in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @ToddSewell said, the external libraries should be in your classpath for the execution too. Try this:

```
java -cp .:"/Library/java/junit.jar" TestRunner
```

Comment: I think you mean "java", not "javac".